# put all the emails coming from the database into array and then send them an email

Tags: php, arrays, email, session

I am trying to put all my emails into an array and send the array by `$_SESSION` and then send them all one email.

```
$getData = $db->prepare('SELECT id,institute,section,name,sudImage,email FROM enrollment_student WHERE institute=? AND section=?');
$getData->bind_param('ii', $insId, $vEnSt);
if ($getData->execute()) {
    $getDataResults = $getData->get_result();
    while ($es = $getDataResults->fetch_array()) {

        $sendEmailToAll = array($es['email']);
        $_SESSION['eta'] = $sendEmailToAll;

        $getUrl = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $_SESSION['efaUrl'] = $getUrl;

        print_r($_SESSION['eta']);
```

The results of the `print_r($_SESSION['eta']);`
is `Array ( [0] => email@hostnile.com )
Array ( [0] => email@hotmail.com )`

but on the other page:

```
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$recipient = $_SESSION['eta'];
$efaUrl = $_SESSION['efaUrl'];

print_r($_SESSION['eta']);

mb_internal_encoding("utf-8");
$subjectText = $subject;
$subject = mb_encode_mimeheader($subjectText, "UTF-8");
$content = '<html><body>';
$content = '<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/></head>';
$content .= $message;
$content .= '</html></body>';

$headers = 'From:admin@academyofart.com' . "\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";

$reTravel = mail($recipient, $subject, $content, $headers);
if ($reTravel == true) {
    //header('Location:' . $efaUrl . '&m=s');
    echo "Done";
} else {
    //header('Location:' . $efaUrl . '&m=f');
    echo "Error";
}
```

try to `print_r` the same `$_SESSION['eta']` it comes `Array ( [0] => email@hotmail.com` as there is one email only and then the results also comes `echo "Error";` sending `Error`.

What I am doing wrong??
Thanks in advance

Comment: You have store an array with one element in $_SESSION['eta'], but next script use it like a string. It's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*notice: all of incoming data should be validated and sanitized! everywhere!*

First script should be fixed:

```
-- remove this two lines
$sendEmailToAll = array($es['email']);
$_SESSION['eta'] = $sendEmailToAll;

-- insert this instead of removed
$_SESSION['eta'][] = $es['email'];
```

Second script changes:

```
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$efaUrl = $_SESSION['efaUrl'];

mb_internal_encoding("utf-8");
$subjectText = $subject;
$subject = mb_encode_mimeheader($subjectText, "UTF-8");
$content = '<html><body>';
$content = '<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/></head>';
$content .= $message;
$content .= '</html></body>';

$headers = 'From:admin@academyofart.com' . "\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";

foreach ($_SESSION['eta'] as $recipient) {

    // I would like to recommend add the last parameter
    // otherwise some of email-servers detect your email as spam   
    $reTravel = mail($recipient, $subject, $content, $headers, '-fadmin@academyofart.com');

    // notice: it will print Done or Error for every email
    if ($reTravel == true) {
        //header('Location:' . $efaUrl . '&m=s');
        echo $recipient.": Done".PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        //header('Location:' . $efaUrl . '&m=f');
        echo $recipient.": Error".PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: I got it but still there is one thing the last email sent twice why is this?

Comment: thanks it's working fine now as Aleksandr said it's should be cleaned `$_SESSION['eta'] = null;`

Comment: I advise to collect all emails in array without setting it to $_SESSION, and set $_SESSION data after the loop. And you don't need to clean it, it will be overwrited.

Answer (score 0):

you're overwrite session variable 'eta', try this

```
$_SESSION['eta'][] = $sendEmailToAll;
```

Comment: it's coming right but still one thing to be sure about I am now getting array repeating it self like so `Array ( [0] => mahmoud_mamdoh@hotmail.com [1] => Array ( [0] => yousef@hostnile.com ) [2] => Array ( [0] => mahmoud_mamdoh@hotmail.com ) ) `  is this OK

Comment: It's wrong...  you need - `$_SESSION['eta'][] = $es['email'];` , and you need to edit your second script, otherwise `mail()` will try receive an array in `recipient` parameter instead of a string with correct email.

Comment: Of course you can do something like that: `mail(implode(',',$recipient), $subject, $content, $headers);` , but if you want to prevent recipients to see another emails, you have to send every mail separately.

Comment: @Wizard thanks for explaining can you please show me an example of how to send every mail separately thanks in advance

Comment: I already tried something like this `$addresses = explode(',', $recipient);

foreach ($recipient as $addresses) {
    $reTravel = mail($recipient, $subject, $content, $headers);

    if ($reTravel == true) {
        //header('Location:' . $efaUrl . '&m=s');
        echo "Done";
    } else {
        //header('Location:' . $efaUrl . '&m=f');
        echo "Error";
    }
}`

Comment: clean variable first - $_SESSION['eta'] = null; then as Wizard says - $_SESSION['eta'][] = $es['email'];

Comment: @Yousef Altaf, made my suggestions as an answer.